# Can not connect via FTP over explicit TLS/SSL

Tags: server, ftp, ssl, curl, filezilla

I have been rather desperate trying to connect via  FTP over explicit TLS/SSL.

I am following this manual: http://repeatexplorer.umbr.cas.cz/static/html/help/manual.html#using-ftp

Here is what I tried:

1.
curl -T bar.pdf -k -v --ftp-ssl -u michalovova.monika@gmail.com:borisV ftp://repeatexplorer.umbr.cas.cz

```
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ 0 successful
> PROT P
< 200 Protection set to Private
> PWD
< 257 "/" is the current directory
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||36950|)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:04 --:--:--     0Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
* got positive EPSV response, but can't connect. Disabling EPSV
> PASV
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,201,144,2).
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:08 --:--:--     0Connection timed out
* couldn't connect to host
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:08 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

1. filezilla

   Status: Resolving address of repeatexplorer.umbr.cas.cz

   Status: Connecting to 147.231.252.6:990...

   Error:  Connection timed out

   Error:  Could not connect to server
2. ftp-ssl repeatexplorer.umbr.cas.cz

   Connected to galaxy.umbr.cas.cz.

   220 ProFTPD 1.3.4a Server (Public Galaxy FTP) [192.168.0.201]

   Name (repeatexplorer.umbr.cas.cz:louna): mich

   234 AUTH SSL successful

   [SSL Cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA]

   331 Password required for mich

   Password:

   230 User mich logged in

   Remote system type is UNIX.

   Using binary mode to transfer files.

   ftp> ls

   200 PORT command successful

   425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out

Any idea what would be easiest way to connect to that server?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: worked for me -- [Try using ftp -p which will begin the client in passive (PASV) mode.](https://superuser.com/questions/356138/cant-connect-to-ftp-server-425-unable-to-build-data-connection-connection-tim)

I believe this has to do with the ports being blocked.  I believe the ports are 9000 - 9020 by default.  A [similar problem on centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/574712/iptables-is-blocking-ftp-for-vms) recommends changing the firewall rules.

I haven't isolated where the problem is with my ports being blocked, but hopefully this points you further in the right direction.